# Where Joomla Files Located

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone please tell me where I can find joomla files? e.g. articles in my file manager, see image.

[image: files]

Cheers

Comment: You may also want to read this: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/what-is-the-joomla-execution-flow-after-a-request-reach-to-index-php-till-the-f/

Comment: Articles are not stored as files, they are stored in the DB. The easiest way to edit them is via the CMS itself (see the links above or https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_new_article). Articles images are generally stored in the images folder. There are other file types of course, but it depends on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to know exactly.

Joomla articles resides in the data base not on files.

If what you're looking for are the files that manage articles, you should look at the component com_content